# How to run jQueryValidation plugin without using a form tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jQueryValidation plugin and I read some of the documentation but I don't know if you can run jqueryvalidator without a form. What I need is run the jqueryvalidator using the event in the button.

Here's some of my code:

```
<div class="row" id="form-validate">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usernamedata">Username</label>
            <select name="username" class="usernamedata form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                <?php if(isset($filter_username)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $filter_username; ?>"><?php echo $get_username; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email_address" placeholder="sample@email.com" value="<?php echo $filter_email; ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date Added</label>
            <div class='input-group date' id='date-added'>
                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="date_added" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" value="<?php echo $filter_date_added; ?>" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="status">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1" <?php ($filter_status == 1) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Enabled</option>
                <option value="0" <?php ($filter_status == 0) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Disabled</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group text-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="filter-data"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I wrap all my needed textfields in the ID **#form-validate**
And I want this onclick event to process the validation

```
$("#filter-data").on('click', function(){
   //do the validation here
   if(!myValidation) {
      //success
   } else {
      //display error
   }
});
```

Comment: As far as I know, you must have form tags for jQuery Validation to run properly

Comment: So it's not possible to use this plugin w/o a form tag? Because in my page there's also a form and I know that only 1 form should be in a specific page.

Comment: That's not necessarily true, You can have more than one form within a same page as long as you can distinguish them separately

Comment: Ah because from the start my understanding is in order to have a proper page there's only 1 form for every page. Thanks for the information. :)